# Unix Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, unix

I have seen the concept of process substitution. But the following code still give me the syntax error

```
script.sh: syntax error at line 44: `<' unexpected

script.sh: syntax error at line 44: `<' unexpected
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=1

FILENAME=$1

JUDGE="YATES"

echo "VALUE OF JUDGE IS $JUDGE"

STATUS=""

#The file is read using while loop , file being supplied as cmd line arg , file simply contains the list of courts . 

#cat $FILENAME | while read LINE

while read LINE

do

#Selecting the filepath here $LINE contains the court every time it iterates    

FILEPATH=/elFZ/dZcollection/$LINE/DETER_JUDGE

#Checking whether the DETER_JUDGE exists or not ,     
cat $FILEPATH >> yatisawhney.txt 2>> yati_errors.txt


#if the DETER_JUDGE file exists then 
if [ $? = 0 ]
    then    

    echo "INSIDE IF"

    STATUS="Yes"

    #cat $FILEPATH | while read -r JUDGELINE

    #open the DETER JUDGE file and read the values and updating the JUDGE variable. 

    while read  JUDGELINE   

    do  

    line_length=$JUDGELINE


    JUDGE=$JUDGE$line_length"||||||"    

    #JUDGE=1000

    done < < ( $FILEPATH )

    echo "Value of judge is $JUDGE"

else
    FILEPATH="N.A."

    STATUS="No"

    JUDGE="N.A."

fi

#here I am not getting the updated value

echo $JUDGE >> JUDGE_NAME

echo $count","$LINE","$STATUS","$JUDGE","$FILEPATH >> judgeData.csv

count=`expr "$count" + 1`

JUDGE=""

done < < ( $FILENAME )
```

I am unable to the fetch the values from the inner while loop. However I am able to fetch them inside the loop, once I get outside the values get lost.

Comment: use http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2):

The process substitution uses the `<(...)` construct, there should be no space between the `<` and the left parenthesis.

To read from a file, you don't need process substitution at all:

```
done < "$FILENAME"
```

Comment: done < "$FILENAME"  is not working in my case , the values in the inner while loop don't appear outside . However I want those values

Comment: What values? Please indent your code so that the loops are visible.

Comment: The code is already being indented , i could put comments here .

Comment: It's not. There's no indentation in the first `while` loop, so it's hard to guess where it ends.